# Arrays.asList() doubt?

Tags: java, collections

People say that `asList` method convert the array into list and its not copying, so every change in 'aList' will reflect into 'a'. So add new values in 'aList' is illegal, since array have fixed size.

But, `asList()` method returns `ArrayList<T>`. How the compiler differentiates line 3 from 5. Line 3 gives me exception (`UnsupportedOperationException`).

```
        String[] a = {"a","b","c","d"};//1
        List<String> aList =  Arrays.asList(a);//2
        aList.add("e");//3
        List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();//4
        b.add("a");//5
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what 'people say'. It matters what the *Javadoc* says.

Answer (score 34):

This List implementation you receive from `Arrays.asList` is a special view on the array - you can't change it's size.

The return type of `Arrays.asList()` is `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` which is often confused with `java.util.ArrayList`. `Arrays.ArrayList` simply shows the array *as a list*.

Comment: +1 I think this is basically the crux of the question.  The OP sees that the return type is ArrayList, and is wondering why it behaves differently from an ArrayList.  Perfectly valid question.

Comment: Andreas_D, the return type of `Arrays.asList(...)` is `java.util.List` and not `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 10):

[Read again](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29), the type of Arrays.asList is:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

which clearly states that asList returns an object that implements *interface java.util.List*, nowhere does it says it will return an instance of *class java.util.ArrayList*.

Next, notice that the documentation on [List.add](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) says:

> boolean add(E e)
>
> Appends the specified element to the end of this list **(optional operation)**.

Technically, everytime you use a variable typed as List (instead of ArrayList), you should always be careful to expect that this method may throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. If you are sure that you will only receive a List implementation that always have the correct semantic of `.add()`, then you can omit the check at the risk of a bug when your assumption is invalidated.

Answer (score 6):

The Return type of Arrays.List is some unknown internal implementation of the List interface and **not** java.util.ArrayList, so you can assign it only to a List type.

If you assign it to an ArrayList for instance it will give you compile time error
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from List to ArrayList"

```
  ArrayList<String> aList =  Arrays.asList(a);// gives Compile time error
```

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))  "Arrays.asList Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) " that means that you are only provided a list view of the Array which IMO is created at runtime and ofcourse you cannot change the size of an array so you can't change size of "Arrays.asList" also.

IMO the internal implementation of Arrays.asList has all the implemented methods which can change the size of the Array as -

```
void add(E e)
{
//some unknown code
throw(java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException);
}
```

so whenever you attempt to alter the size of the Array it throws the UnsupportedOperationException.

Still if you want to add some new items to an ArrayList by using such a syntax, you can do so by creating a subclass of Arraylist(preferably by using anonymous subclass of ArrayList). You can pass the return type of Arrays.List to the constructor of ArrayList, (ie. public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)) something like this -

```
List<String> girlFriends = new java.util.ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Rose", "Leena", "Kim", "Tina"));
girlFriends.add("Sarah");
```

Now you can easily add Sarah to your GF list using the same syntax.

Answer (score 5):

`asList()` doesn't return a `java.util.ArrayList`, it returns a `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`. This class doesn't even extend `java.util.ArrayList`, so its behaviour can be (and is) completely different.

The `add()` method is inherited from `java.util.AbstractList`, which by default just throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: No, asList returns a List. What you are describing may be true for a specific Java implementation, but is not anything you can rely on.

Comment: @jarnbjo - This is true for both Sun Java and GNU Classpath and probably any other implementations as it's the easiest way to do it. As the question was about how the compiler can tell, I though a concrete example would be easiest to understand.

Answer (score 3):

It's an exception and not a compiler error. It is thrown when the program is run and not at the compile time. Basically the actual class that Arrays.asList will return has a `throw UnsupporteOperationException` inside the `add()` method.

To be more specific `Arrays.asList` will return an inner class defined inside the `Arrays` class that is derived from `AbstractList` and does not implement the `add` method. The `add` method from the `AbstractList` is actually throwing the exception.

Answer (score 3):

You're assuming that `Arrays.asList()` returns an `ArrayList`, but that's not the case. `Arrays.asList()` returns an unspecified `List` implementation. That implementaton simply throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` on each unsupported method.

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is the `List` implementation returned by

```
List<String> aList =  Arrays.asList(a);
```

If you look at the source code in `Arrays` you will see that it contains an internal private static class `ArrayList`. This is not the same as `java.util.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

asList returns a fixed-size list, so that you cannot add new elements to it. Because the list it returns is really a "view" of the array it was created from ('a' in your case), it makes sense that you won't be able to add elements - just like you can't add elements to an array. See the docs for [asList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)