# Adding Elements to List Java

Tags: java

Why I am unable to Add element to List after assigning values from to Arrays.asList

```
List<Integer> sam = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
sam.add(5);

for (Integer integer : sam)
{
  System.out.println(integer);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792160/arrays-aslist-doubt  
This will help you to understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4)` creates a "list view" on an array whose size can't change. That way we can use and access an array through the `List` interface.

If you want a list in which you can add values but still use the convenient `Arrays.asList(..)`, simply do:

```
List<Integer> sam = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
```

Comment: Is it that by getting list view, we can perform operations like we do on a list?

Comment: Yes. All methods from the `List` interface are available but some have limitations: like `add` won't work - because it's still an array.

Answer (score 6):

`Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-size List. Adding or removing elements from this list is not allowed, it is possible however to modify the elements inside this list using the `set` method.

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(a); // this is not java.util.ArrayList
}

private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable {
    ArrayList(E[] array) {
        if (array==null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        a = array;
    }

    public E set(int index, E element) { 
        E oldValue = a[index];
        a[index] = element;
        return oldValue;            
    }

    // add() and remove() methods are inherited from AbstractList
}

public abstract class AbstractList<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> 
    implements List<E> {

    public E remove(int index) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public void add(int index, E element) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[As per docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

> **Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.** (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and implements RandomAccess.

So after you created that you cannot add elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

`asList(T... a)` Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

```
List<Integer> sam = new ArrayList<Integer>();
sam.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
sam.add(5);

for (Integer integer : sam)
{
  System.out.println(integer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the documentation of the method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

The method Arrays.asList returned a fixed-size list view, so you can not add elements using the list.

Anyway, the same question is answered here:

[Arrays.asList() doubt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792160/arrays-aslist-doubt)