# What is the difference between multiple implementations of ArrayList in the (Java8) source code

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I was trying to understand `Stream`s in Java8 and intermittently I stumbled upon an interesting thing in the source code of Java8: `ArrayList` seems to be implemented twice:

- The obvious one: `java.util.ArrayList`
- The non-obvious one: `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`, which is a private class.

One odd difference is that the normal version is way bigger, and implements `List<E>`, whereas `Arrays.ArrayList` does not do so (directly).

Why is it defined twice? And why with the same name?

Comment: It's not new in Java 8 - see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792160/arrays-aslist-doubt/4792194#4792194

Comment: These classes happen to share the same name, but are not supposed to fulfill the same role. The `private` class is an implementation detail inside `Arrays` and is providing a `List` view on an array. It could have been called `ArrayViewList` or something, and maybe it helps in understanding to pretend it was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually its there ever since `Arrays.asList()` introduced. Array's ArrayList is view of the underlying array. If the Array gets changed the ArrayList will get effected and viceversa.

The main benefit, No additional space required because it wont copy the array to a new object (ArrayList), also no additional time to copy the elements.