# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException while adding element to a list

Tags: java

For a string "a3tx2z" The output of this should be "attttxzzz", or for "12x" it should be "2xxx". I checked everything and they work. but when i want to print "ttt" in the place of 3, there is a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` at line 28 `l.add(i, s1);`. What is wrong here?

```
package xyz;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class xyz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        xyz n = new xyz();
        n.blowup("a3tx2z");

    }

    public String blowup(String str){

        String[] array = str.split("");
        List<String> l = Arrays.asList(array);

        for(int i=0; i<l.size(); i++){
            String s1 = l.get(i);
            if(s1.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")){
                String s2 = l.get(i+1);
                if(!(s2.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"))){
                    int t = Integer.parseInt(s1);
                    while(t>0){
                       l.add(i, s1);
                       t--;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
        for(String x: l){
            System.out.print(x);
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Be careful; it's not a java.util.ArrayList, but a [`java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4792194/899126)!

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965747/why-i-get-unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-to-remove-from-the-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting a `List` returned by [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-), but it's just a wrapper around an array, so you can't `add` anything to it.

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

If you must `add` to it, then create another `ArrayList` out of that list.

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: Thanks. I did what you wrote but now the program hangs at the same line(28).